# how to disable/enable a workflow in SPD 2007?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a workflow in SPD 2007
but i would like to disable it and later enable it back on to start running.
I haven't really came across how you could switch it on and off.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've published the workflow and want to disable it, you can open it in SharePoint Designer and then hit the Back button in the Workflow screen, deselect all startup options and click the finish button.

You can also go into the Workflow settings of the list/library and toggle the current workflow radio button to No New Instances or something to that affect.

Answer (score 2):

With SharePoint Designer, you can pause workflows until a column changes or until a certain date has past.  Are you looking for more functionality than that?

Comment: iOnline247 i have created a workflow and basically i don't want it to run.But i don't want to delete it so i can use it again when i need it.It fires now when an item is inserted or updated.

Comment: I would suggest to keep using SharePoint Designer and get comfortable with it.  Everything you have described so far, that you want to do; can be done using the wizards within SPD already.